# What's the meaning of 'thin air'?

Tags: meaning

I know that the idiom, 'vanish into thin air' means 'disappear mysteriously'. However, I'm not quite sure what 'thin air' means in the idiom.

From this [post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-idiomatic-meaning-of-the-emerge-out-of-thin-air), it seems 'thin air' means foggy air. But in this [post](https://www.quora.com/What-does-thin-air-mean), 'thin air' means the air in the high altitude. It seems both meanings work. It disappears into the fog or it disappears into the high place. Both of them give a sense of mystery.

What do you usually imagine when you read the 'thin air' in a sentence?

Comment: From the full OED, **thin** 3b: *(transferred and figurative) Wanting body or substance; unsubstantial; intangible. Also in **to vanish (melt, etc.) into thin air**: to disappear completely from sight or existence (formerly only of spirits). More rarely **to come (etc.) out of thin air**. Now chiefly colloquial.* There's no particular allusion to fog or mist, and this idiomatic usage has nothing whatsoever to do with atmospheric pressure being lower at high altitudes. It's just that air ***is*** "thin, insubstantial", by its very nature.

Comment: So, it's not a movement of something away into air that is thin, but "becoming thin air". Someone "turns into thin air".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this expression, I take "thin air" to stand in *contrast* to heavy fog or thick smoke.

It's a little bit mysterious when a stage magician vanishes in a puff of smoke.  That puff of smoke probably hides him from view just long enough for him to jump through a trap door, or something like that.

It's much more mysterious when a magician vanishes without the puff of smoke.  He isn't hidden from view.  We should have seen him jump through the trap door, if that's what he did.  So, where did he go?  How did he go?  There was nothing to hide him.  He just vanished into thin air.